# how do you animate a d3 chart title?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, ionic-framework

I'm tryinf to make a pie chart using [angular-nvd3](https://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) - the char works and is animated, but I want to animate the percentage in the "title". So, as the char animates, the percentage will go up. any suggestions?

```
$timeout(function(){    
    ctrl.data[0].y = $scope.goal.part; //some number greater than 0
},500)

ctrl.data = [{
key: "Steps",
y: 0,
color: ctrl.colors.color2
},{
key: "Left to goal",
y: $scope.goal.whole,
color: ctrl.colors.color
}];

ctrl.options = {
chart: {
  type: 'pieChart',
  height: 325,
  x: function(d){return d.key;},
  y: function(d){return d.y;},
  showLabels: false,
  duration: 1200,
  labelThreshold: 0.01,
  labelSunbeamLayout: true,
  width: 325,
  title: d3.format('%')(ctrl.data[0].y/ctrl.data[1].y),
  donut: true,
  donutRatio: 0.70,
  tooltips: false,
  showLegend: false
}
};




    <nvd3 options="ctrl.options" data="ctrl.data"></nvd3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the title out of the chart and create a title object at the same level as chart.

Try like this:

```
ctrl.options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'pieChart',
    height: 325,
    x: function(d){return d.key;},
    y: function(d){return d.y;},
    showLabels: false,
    duration: 1200,
    labelThreshold: 0.01,
    labelSunbeamLayout: true,
    width: 325,
    donut: true,
    donutRatio: 0.70,
    tooltips: false,
    showLegend: false
  },
  title :{ 
    enable: true, 
    text: d3.format('%')(ctrl.data[0].y/ctrl.data[1].y),
  }
};
```

[Described here in the docs Wrapper section](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart#doc_wrapper)

Comment: as it is now is shows in the middle of the donut. if i bring it out - its not any easier to access. thanks